# Powershell Multiple variables in foreach loop getting AWS-EC2 instance info

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I need to get instanceId and PrivateIpAddress from all my EC2 instances in my environment and insert into table.  I have this but doesn't seem to work. I seem to get everything not just the IP and ID.

```
$instancestate = (get-ec2instance).RunningInstance 

foreach ($instances in $instancestate)
{
 $query = "INSERT INTO prodinstances (Idinstance, IPAddress)
VALUES ('$instances.InstanceId','$instances.PrivateIpAddress')" 
$Rows = Execute-MySQLNonQuery $conn $query 
}
```

If I change the code

```
$instancestate = (get-ec2instance).RunningInstance.InstanceId
```

I get the ID and can insert it in the database. I can also change it to

```
$instancestate = (get-ec2instance).RunningInstance.PrivateIpAddress
```

and get the IPAddress and insert that into the database,  but when i combine them I get all the info for the EC2 instances which does have .instanceId and .PrivateIpAddress in the list when I hover over the variable $instances.    Any Idea how to get both those parameters.  My code seems correct but alas it is not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"VALUES ('$instances.InstanceId'"
```

is the same as

```
"VALUES ('" + $instances + ".InstanceId'"
```

Now it doesn't seem correct. You need `$()` around it, inside the string:

```
"VALUES ('$($instances.InstanceId)'"
```

Comment: Thanks,  i figured it out last night by assigning the output to a variable like this, but your way @TessellatingHecker is much more eloquent...   
    $MyID =$instances.InstanceId
    $MyIP = $instances.PrivateIpAddress
    $query = "INSERT INTO prodinstances (Idinstance, IPAddress) VALUES     ('$MyID','$MyIP')" 
   $Rows = Execute-MySQLNonQuery $conn $query 
}

Comment: I had to change the code and insert only if does not exist but this doesn't seem to be working, it inserts regardless  `$instancestate = (get-ec2instance).RunningInstance 
foreach ($instances in $instancestate)
{
$query = "INSERT INTO prodinstances (Idinstance, IPAddress) SELECT Idinstance, IPAddress FROM prodinstances 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT Idinstance, IPAddress FROM prodinstances 
WHERE Idinstance = '$($instances.InstanceId)' and IPAddress = '$($instances.PrivateIpAddress)')"
   $Rows = Execute-MySQLNonQuery $conn $query 
}`

Answer (score 1):

Fixed works like a charm...

```
$instancestate = (get-ec2instance).RunningInstance 
foreach ($instances in $instancestate)
{

$query = "insert into prodinstances (idinstance,IPAddress) VALUES  ('$($instances.InstanceId)', '$($instances.PrivateIpAddress)') 
ON duplicate key update    idinstance='$($instances.InstanceId)',IPAddress='$($instances.PrivateIpAddr ess)'"
$Rows = Execute-MySQLNonQuery $conn $query

}
```